# How to use canvas draw functions inside an XML-defined view

Tags: android, android-layout

I don't want to create a new View object, I have a simple View already defined in my XML and I just want to draw some bars on top of it.

In the XML, I have a blank LinearLayout containing this:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/bars"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey" />
```

And then the code I have to work on. In this example, I'm testing it by simply drawing a small blue circle:

```
View bars = (View) this.findViewById(R.id.bars);

Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);

mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
c.drawCircle(5, 5, 8, mPaint);

bars.draw(c);
```

The error I get is a NullPointerException when I try to set the color. If I take out that line, then I get an error when I try to drawCircle. How can I do what I want?

**Edit - Error Log (I took out setColor):**

```
05-19 00:56:14.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2422): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-19 00:56:14.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2422): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aheadstudios.talkalytics/com.aheadstudios.talkalytics.ViewStatsPrototype}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 00:56:14.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
05-19 00:56:14.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
05-19 00:56:14.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
05-19 00:56:14.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
05-19 00:56:14.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-19 00:56:14.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-19 00:56:14.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
05-19 00:56:14.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 00:56:14.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-19 00:56:14.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
05-19 00:56:14.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
05-19 00:56:14.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-19 00:56:14.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2422): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 00:56:14.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at android.graphics.Canvas.drawCircle(Canvas.java:961)
05-19 00:56:14.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at com.aheadstudios.talkalytics.MultiStatsData.commonSetup(MultiStatsData.java:68)
05-19 00:56:14.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at com.aheadstudios.talkalytics.MultiStatsData.<init>(MultiStatsData.java:50)
05-19 00:56:14.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at com.aheadstudios.talkalytics.ViewStatsPrototype.setupMultiStatsData(ViewStatsPrototype.java:48)
05-19 00:56:14.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at com.aheadstudios.talkalytics.ViewStatsPrototype.onCreate(ViewStatsPrototype.java:43)
05-19 00:56:14.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-19 00:56:14.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-19 00:56:14.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
05-19 00:56:14.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Comment: @Sree But I need all the canvas draw functions, drawables seem to only give you a basic shape? I'm going to be drawing bars w/ words inside them.

Comment: ok look this http://staticallytyped.wordpress.com/2011/04/16/android-custom-xml-attributes-and-views/

Comment: have you initialized `mPaint` object ? I think there might be problem with its initialization.

Comment: I give up, I'm just going to create a new custom view object so I can override onDraw.

Comment: That's the only way to do it.  When you create a generic Canvas with new it isn't attached to the screen

Answer (score 0):

mPaint = new Paint();

Then instead of bars.draw(c)

Add

bars.setBackgroundDrawable(new BackgroundDrawable(b));